Relation between difficulty and number of leading zero bits in hash?
What's the relation between the difficulty and the number of zero bits in the hash?
For example, as of writing, the best hash is:
000000000000000000028a424dde3445bfe99f5097b513b245c5a5a9bded20c4

This is (19 zeroes) × (4 bits) = 76 leading zero bits. The difficulty is 83126997340024.61.

Leading zeroes are irrelevant in Bitcoin

If you just want a formula, then N leading zero bits corresponds to a difficulty of 2^(N - 32.000022) approximately. But as pointed out in the other comment, "leading zero bits" is a simplification, and is not how Bitcoin works internally.
